# Document scrolling by itself when moving sticky block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky block on my site. It has 3 conditions:

- By default this block is in header, static position
- When bootom of the viewport reaches top side of the block it becomes sticky (always stays on the bottom of the screen)
- When bootom of the viewport reaches top side of the footer the block becomes static, but it is inserted before footer

**THE PLOBLEM**
On the Android Chrome functionality works incorrectly: when the block is fastened before footer (we scrolled to the bottom of the document) we scroll to top (block becomes sticky) and document scrolls to the middle of the document (whaaat). It is like it positions relatively to some blocks in `main` block. Why does it happen? On the PC chrome everything seems good.

The code (`buttonsBlock` is sticky):

```
var buttonsPrimaryPosition = $(".buttons-320").offset().top; //position of block on load

  function makeButtonsSticky() {

      var buttonsBlock = $(".buttons-320");
      var buttonsPosition = buttonsBlock.offset().top + 75; // bottom side of the block position, 75 height of the block
      var totalHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(); //bottom side of the viewport coordinate
      var footerTop = $(document).height() - $(".footer").height(); //top side of footer coordinate


        if ( totalHeight >= buttonsPrimaryPosition + 75 && totalHeight < warrantyTop ) {
          buttonsBlock.appendTo($(".header"));
          buttonsBlock.addClass("buttons-320-fixed");
          buttonsBlock.removeClass("buttons-320-bottom");    
        } else if ( totalHeight >= footerTop ) {
          $(".footer").before(buttonsBlock);
          buttonsBlock.removeClass("buttons-320-fixed");
          buttonsBlock.addClass("buttons-320-bottom");
        } else {
          buttonsBlock.appendTo($(".header"));
          buttonsBlock.removeClass("buttons-320-fixed");
          buttonsBlock.removeClass("buttons-320-bottom");

        };
  };

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    makeButtonsSticky();
  });
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons-320 {
    background: #2693c5 url('img/buttons-border.png') no-repeat center;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
  .buttons-320-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 150;
  }
  .buttons-320-bottom {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="button-320"><>
</header >
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: That code looks weird. What are the `footer` and `header` classes? Is button panel supposed to stick to the top when user scrolls and when entire page is smaller than `warrantyTop`, and stick to the bottom when footer is on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in adding to `head` following phrase:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```